# Application name is displayed with its extension when QSystemTrayIcon's showMessage is used in Windows 10

Tags: qt, qsystemtrayicon

I'm using QSystemTrayIcon to display notification in Windows 10. 
Along with the notification, the application name is also displayed.
The problem here is the app name is displayed along with the extension(.exe).

[image: Screenshot]

How can the extension(.exe) be removed from the notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line to your `.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_TARGET_DESCRIPTION = "Whatever"
```

It should change the process name (both in the notifications and in the task manager) to "Whatever".

More variables like this can be found here: [Qmake Variables Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html)

Note from the documentation:

> This is only utilized if the `VERSION` or `RC_ICONS` variable is set and the `RC_FILE` and `RES_FILE` variables are not set.

---

### Step-by-step instructions for creating a test application

1. Create Qt Widgets Application project, containing a `QWidget` based widget
2. Create `images` directory in the project folder, put an icon file into it (for this example let it be `icon.ico`)
3. Add a resource file to the project
4. To that resource file add prefix `/`, then "Add Files", selecting `./images/icon.ico`
5. In `main.cpp` change the code to following:

```
    #include "widget.h"
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QIcon>
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QCoreApplication::setApplicationName(APP_NAME);
    
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        a.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/images/icon.ico"));
    
        Widget w;
        w.setWindowTitle(qApp->applicationName());
        w.setWindowIcon(qApp->windowIcon());
        w.show();
    
        return a.exec();
    }
```

6. In `widget.cpp` change code to following:

```
    #include "widget.h"
    #include "ui_widget.h"
    
    #include <QSystemTrayIcon>
    
    Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
        : QWidget(parent)
        , ui(new Ui::Widget)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    
        QSystemTrayIcon *trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(qApp->windowIcon(), this);
        trayIcon->show();
    
        connect(trayIcon, &QSystemTrayIcon::activated, [=]() {
            trayIcon->showMessage("Title", "Message");
        });
    }
    
    Widget::~Widget()
    {
        delete ui;
    }
```

7. To the bottom of the project (`.pro`) file add following:

```
    DEFINES +=  APP_NAME=\\\"AppName\\\"
    
    QMAKE_TARGET_DESCRIPTION = "Whatever"
    
    win32:RC_ICONS += images/icon.ico
```

8. Save, run qmake (Build -> Run qmake), rebuild project
9. Start the application. Now the window title should be "AppName", which came from APP_NAME define, both window and tray icon - icon.ico, and the process name in task manager and notifications - "Whatever". You can make the app display a notification by clicking on the tray icon. Notification should look like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! But this doesn't seem to fix my issue. Please suggest me some alternatives :)

Comment: I've tested this method and it works fine for me. I believe the answer wasn't clear on all the details needed for this to work, so I've added a step-by-step instructions to the answer.

Comment: You also have to set the VERSION for this to work: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-target-description